# getSystemResourceAsStream returns null while parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create a document object from a local XML file.

This part of my code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factoria = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder constructor = factoria.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document documento = constructor.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(URLXML));
```

causes the following exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null    at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)

getSystemResourceAsStream() is only supposed to return null when it can't find the source, and I've checked that the file url is stored correctly in the string (it's  C:\file.xml, which is the correct location of the file).

So what is failing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you asking the *classloader* for the resource though? And it sounds like you've just got a filename rather than a resource name... so why not use `FileInputStream`?

Comment: I'm asking the classloader because according to the information I read not using it might cause portability problems in certain OS's. Is C:\file.xml not a valid resource name? what would be a correct resource name then?

Comment: It's not a valid resource name, and this isn't something that the classloader would be likely to serve anyway. And if you're worried about portability, `c:\file.xml` isn't going to be a valid file on most OSes. If you're trying to load a file, just use `FileInputStream` - and make sure you've got an appropriate filename for the system you're using.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to redo the code to use  FileInputStream instead.  what would be an appropiate filename under windows? I'm taking it straight from a JFileChooser, should I be formatting it somehow first? (I'm a little lost, though, I'm a student and this is the first time I'm trying to make a project like this.)

Comment: If you're taking the filename from a JFileChooser, then that's fine. The same filename wouldn't work on a different OS, but then you'd expect the user to pick a different file...

Answer (score 0):

keep file.xml in classpath. keep it in WEB-INF if your's is a web app or keep it in the folder from where you are executing the java command for standalone application.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've tried with the file inside the classpath, but the result seems to be the same.

Comment: can you please brief on your environment...are you using any IDE?, is it web app or standalone app...?

Comment: It's a standalone app. I'm using java 1.7.  I'm using Eclipse  (kepler), which is where I'm running the code from.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error using the `getSystemResourceAsStream`, so instead of using that I used:

```
parser.parse(new File(""), handler);
```

and it worked fine.